# PHP Practices for first time web-programmer

Tags: php

I have this idea for a website that's been floating around my head for quite sometime now and now have finally decided to get to work on it. Due to the nature of the project and my experience I am getting comfortable with the idea of running it as a PHP+MySQL application on an Apache server.

This is my first time doing web programming of any sort(I have a background in sysadmin and mainframe systems coding) and I am pretty unsure of what practices to take into consideration so that I don't find myself undoing/redoing things later in the project. Considering all the flak the language has taken on StackOverflow(which can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233030/worst-php-practice-found-in-your-experience) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309300/defend-php-convince-me-it-isnt-horrible)) it would be nice to have a set of common mistakes to watch out for for a beginner like me. I did find this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/694246/how-is-php-done-the-right-way) outlining things to avoid in PHP but most of the points made little sense to someone like me who's just setting out in PHP.

Do you have any suggestions, tips or tutorials outlining common gotcha's in the language which might come back later in the project demanding entire rewrites.

For what it's worth I am currently working my way through [Programming PHP(O'Reilly)](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596006815/) and [PHP in Action(Manning)](http://www.manning.com/reiersol/).

Answer (score 1):

I was in a very similar position a couple years ago, having come from a NOS background myself.

I actually started with PHP and MySQL for dummies. Once I had absorbed the knowledge contained therein, I hit the Web (I used SitePoint a lot, like Boushley recommended) and I read a couple of O'Reilley's book on the subject.

Once thing I will tell you, is that if you want to streamline your understanding and your efficiency, I have found great success with a number of MVC frameworks(CodeIgnitor, CakePHP, etc). If you have no idea what MVC is, I recommend finding out. Now that I use MVC, my code is easier to understand, modify, troubleshoot, etc.

And honestly, half of the learning in PHP is running into those common mistakes and learning from them. Its hard to appreciate those 'common mistakes' until you make them.

Don't worry about HOW you are going to learn, just START leaning!

Answer (score 1):

If I could give you one piece of advice, it'd be to use a framework - they will make your life so much easier. They take away all the repetitive code from programming websites, handle security concerns and abstract lots of things, as well as make you build your website using a pattern such as Model-View-Controller.

I highly recommend the [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com) framework for it's simplicity, power, great documentation and ease of use, but there are plenty of other good frameworks too. There are lots of questions on SO on this so have a quick search. There is a fantastic introductory screencast on CodeIgniter (soon to be a series) from BinaryCake, so [check that out here](http://binarycake.com/screencasts/mastering-codeigniter-part-1/).

I hope that's helped! If you have any PHP concerns, feel free to message me - it's my area of expertise (along with CodeIgniter) and I love it!

Answer (score 1):

While still developing, have all errors show up:

```
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```

Can save a lot of time (in case of say, typos in variable names). Change this when it goes live to not display or only display "real" errors depending on the type of site and security levels involved (you don't want everyone to know paths and variable names and such..).

Find a variable/function naming convention (under_scores vs camelCase vs..) that suits you and stick to it. Also, classes go in the /class directory, includes in /inc etc. Both these make it easier to understand your own code years from now. Oh, and the same goes for coding style, I guess: choose one and stick to it (indentation, bracket style, ..).

Comment your code :-) Personally I also have a little log at the end of longer files that shows when I did what and why. Each addition is timestamped, and the same timestamp is also in the comments behind the change itself, as the line number on which it sits can easily change. Similarly, in an included file containing a bunch of functions, I have the list of function names in a comment at the top of the file, with a one-line description behind them.

Finally on security (though this should really be your first concern ;-) ), treat *all* user input as suspect. That's POST & GET data, cookies, user-agent string, search strings - anything that is supplied by the browser. It's trivial to change cookie data or change/add form items.
Read up on SQL injection & XSS attacks, and look at PHP's relatively new data filter functions: http://php.net/manual/en/intro.filter.php

Answer (score 0):

Google any of these to get some good reading

- Don't use register_globals
- Turn off magic_quotes - escape all user entered input in SQL statements
- Escape any user entered input printed with htmlspecialchars()

Plus a lot more... These are some common things to watch out for though.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of great websites out there with lots of tutorials.  One that comes to mind is Site Point.  They'll try their best to sell you a book or two while your're there, but they do have some decent articles. This article for instance discusses some common security blunders in php.

http://www.sitepoint.com/article/php-security-blunders/

They have lots of them...

http://www.sitepoint.com/search/search.php?ps=10&q=php&submit=Search

Also a nettuts.com has a load of tutorials an things of that nature.  They're more all across the board though.

http://nettuts.com/

And I think pretty much everywhere you look you'll see the common ones like watch out for register_globals, magic_quotes...

Answer (score 0):

one good book to look at that is also free to download [here](http://www.computer-books.us/php_2.php) covers beginner to advanced PHP techniques and is good way to learn good standards :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a framework and use Object Oriented Programming

Answer (score 0):

Books are great for learning additional languages, but for your first one, a good video tutorial is a great way to go!

Register for a Lynda.com account (google: lynda trial) and sign up for as many one day trials as you need (or be a good honest person and purchase a week). They have a pretty good beginner and advanced PHP series of video tutorials which are (IMHO) a great way to learn your first language.

A tip: If you can start programming Object Orientedly from the get-go, you will save some time in the future and learn good practice from the start, luckily the advanced tutorials cover this!

Here's a link: http://www.lynda.com/home/DisplayCourse.aspx?lpk2=435

I've never taken this particular course (when I learned a few years ago, it was different), but I just recommended this to a friend (who was just starting), and he really liked it!

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you're new to programming in general, A database backed web application is likely to be a bumpy ride.  You will probably be programming in at least two, real programming languages, PHP  and SQL, and if you're going to do anything of modest complexity, JavaScript too.  Keeping them strait will be rough, because they are all quite different.

Just to warm up to programming, you might want to start instead using a more focused learning excercies, such as working through the [Euler Project](http://projecteuler.net/) problems, or [Code Kata](http://codekata.com/).

Either way, Try to pick up good habits wherever you learn about them, including the popular suggestion here of using an MVC framework for the heavy lifting.